# Cross Database Relation doctrine 2 and php

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How can I implement this code in doctrine 2:

```
 Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://root@localhost/doctrine_test1', 'doctrine_test1');
Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://root@localhost/doctrine_test2', 'doctrine_test2');
```

any alternate. I am using this code for connection:

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array("/path/to/entity-files");
$isDevMode = false;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'foo',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

example scenario:

```
--databse_a
CREATE TABLE User (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    address_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

--databse_b
CREATE TABLE Address (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE database_a.User ADD FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES database_b.Address(id);
```

Generate Entities and then try to fech results. You will get errors.

**error in log**: The target-entity Address cannot be found in 'User#address_id'.

Comment: What about having a look at the manual? What is not working with the code you posted?

Comment: I am facing problem when I am trying to make cross db relation. Doctrine giving fatal error in this case. Entities are generated but records are not fetching. 
    /**
     * @var \SystementitySye
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SystementitySye")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idsystem_sye_wfl", referencedColumnName="id_sye")
     * })
     */
    private $idsystemSyeWfl;

Comment: Even a fatal error will have some detailed message, either displayed in your browser or logged in the server's error log. Please find it and attach it to your question, not in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a connection with the user which has authority to access multiple databases like db1 and db2 both.

Then you will just make some changes in your generated entity files. You will add database name before table name like:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="database_a.User", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id", columns={"address_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="address_id", columns={"address_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
*/
class User
{
```

You can download running example code from [github](https://github.com/flik/zend-1-CRUD-with-doctrine-2-and-unitphp)

Comment: Here is another good tutorial for this purpose: https://rapidsol.blogspot.com/2017/12/tutorial-doctrine-2-linux.html